# Apache PDFBox to open temporary created PDF file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using apache pdfbox 2.x version and I am trying to read a temp created file.
Below is my code to create a temp file and read it:

```
Path mergedTempFile = null;
    
        try {
            mergedTempFile = Files.createTempFile("merge_", ".pdf");
            PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(mergedTempFile.toFile());
```

But it gives error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1098)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2577)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:2560)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:219)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1099)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1082)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1006)
    at com.howtodoinjava.demo.PdfboxApi.test(PdfboxApi.java:326)
    at com.howtodoinjava.demo.PdfboxApi.main(PdfboxApi.java:317)
```

From this link I have got a reference but it did not help anyway:
[Similar Issue Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734829/apache-pdfbox-refuses-to-open-temporary-created-pdf-file)

Please help me with this. Still, I can not get rid of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PDDocument.load(...)` is used to parse an existing PDF.

The passed temporary file (`mergedTempFile`) is empty, thus the exception. Just create a `PDDocument` with the constructor (resides in-memory) and later save it with `PDDocument.save(...)`.

```
Path mergedTempFile = null;
try {
    mergedTempFile = Files.createTempFile("merge_", ".pdf");
    try (PDDocument pdDocument = new PDDocument()) {

        // add content
        pdDocument.addPage(new PDPage()); // empty page as an example

        pdDocument.save(mergedTempFile.toFile());
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    // exception handling
}

// use mergedTempFile for further logic
```